# Unable to resolve Spring AOP types in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, import, spring-aop

I created a new Spring boot project and was trying to implement some AOP concerns.

However, my code simply doesn't recognize the Classes from AOP. I checked and confirmed that `spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar` is indeed present in Maven dependencies and JRE Runtime Libraries.

My code yet is very simple:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

     @Around("execution(*  com.springboot.service.*(..)) ")
      public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) throws Throwable {

      }
}
```

But in this code `Aspect cannot be resolved to a type` and same for other annotation and classes like `Joinpoint` and `@Around`. Other Spring annotation and classes work perfectly fine, ex. @Component, @Controllers etc.. and the project in itself runs fine without AOP.

I have already tried cleaning and re-building the project.

What can I be missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Aspect` is located in the `spring-aspects.jar` or one of it's dependencies. add it as dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks..this works. I am new to Spring and expected these annotation to be present in the AOP jar. Any particular reason for them not being present in the single jar ?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Not sure, modularisation maybe

Answer (score 1):

The `@Aspect` and `@Around` (and other such) annotations are part of the `org.aspectj` `aspectjweaver` artifact which is an [optional compile dependency in your version of `spring-aop`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.7.RELEASE).

You have to include it explicitly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.13</version>
</dependency>
```